# Activerecord audit gem that writes to elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, audit

We want to audit some changes to our Activerecord models, and I am looking for gem that can helps us with that.

I found https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited, but as far as I understand, it logs to the main program database (in our case MySql)

I want the same functionality, but writing logs to elasticsearch instead. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `audited` gem supports this. But I believe you can monkey patch the audit model like this.

```
require 'elasticsearch/persistence/model'
module Audited
  class Audit
    include Elasticsearch::Persistence::Model
  end
end
```

Comment: Have u tried to do this? I do not really like moneypatching like this - it can be unmantainable (

Comment: if it is that easy - why audited team does not do it?

Comment: @GeorgyBuranov I said I believe this will work. I have not tried this.